# Exporting to text in Python

Tags: python, text, export

Part of my assignment is to export to text if the user selects that option. I seem to have everything right except that one part. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? Do i need to add something somewhere else in the code for this to work properly? I am getting error that `automobilelist` is not defined when I select Option 6.

```py
class Automobile:
    # constructor, it takes parameters make, model, year and mileage
    def __init__(self,aMake,aModel,aColor,aYear,aMileage):
        # assign passed values to instance variables
        self.setMake(aMake)  # string
        self.setModel(aModel)  # string
        self.setColor(aColor) # string
        self.setYear(aYear)   # int
        self.setMileage(aMileage)  # int

    # setter of make
    # it takes 1 parameter make
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def setMake(self, aMake):
        self.__make = aMake

    # getter of make
    # it doesn't take any parameters
    # it returns make
    def getMake(self):
        return self.__make

    # setter of model
    # it takes 1 parameter model
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def setModel(self, aModel):
        self.__model = aModel

    # getter of model
    # it doesn't take any parameters
    # it returns model
    def getModel(self):
        return self.__model

    # setter of color
    # it takes 1 parameter color
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def setColor(self, aColor):
        self.__color = aColor
        return True

    # getter of color
    # it doesn't take any parameters
    # it returns color
    def getColor(self):
        return self.__color

    # setter of year
    # it takes 1 parameter year
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def setYear(self, aYear):
        self.__year = aYear

    # getter of year
    # it doesn't take any parameters
    # it returns year
    def getYear(self):
        return self.__year

    # setter of mileage
    # it takes 1 parameter year
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def setMileage(self, aMileage):
        self.__mileage = aMileage

    # getter of mileage
    # it doesn't take any parameters
    # it returns mileage
    def getMileage(self):
        return self.__mileage

    # string representation of the instance variables
    # it doesn't take any parameters
    # it returns string form of object
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}, {}, {}, {}, {}".format(self.getMake(),self.getModel(),self.getColor(),self.getYear(),self.getMileage())

class Automobiledealership:

    # constructor
    # it initializes the empty automobile list
    def __init__(self):
        self.__automobilelist = []

    # adds automobile to dealership
    # it takes automobile class object as parameter
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def addAutomobile(self, automobile):
        self.__automobilelist.append(automobile)

    # removes automobile from dealership
    # it takes index of automobile in the list as parameter
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def removeAutomobile(self, index):
        del self.__automobilelist[index-1]

    # returns automobile from dealership
    # it takes index of automobile in the list as parameter
    # it returns automobile object located at that index
    def getAutomobile(self, index):
        return self.__automobilelist[index-1]

    # prints the list of automobiles
    # it doesn't take any parameters
    # it doesn't returns anything
    def printAutomobileList(self):
        if len(self.__automobilelist)==0:
            print("No automobiles in dealership")
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.__automobilelist)):
                print("{}. {}".format(i+1,self.__automobilelist[i]))


    # add some automobiles to the dealership for Sample Inventory
def addSampleAutomobiles(automobiles):
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Ford", "Focus", "Red", 2019, 8000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Toyota","Corolla","White",2007,65000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Ford","Endura","Black",2019,5000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Audio","A1","White",2016,23000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Toyota", "Camry", "Red", 2000, 25000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Ford","Everest","Black",2017,16000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Mazda","MX5","Red",2015,33000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Ford","Escape","Grey",2018,15000))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile("Toyota", "Prius", "Red", 2010, 35000))

def addAutomobile(automobiles):
    make = input("Please enter Make >> ")
    model = input("Please enter Model >> ")
    color = input("Please enter Color >> ")
    year = int(input("Please enter Year >> "))
    mileage = int(input("Please enter Mileage >> "))
    automobiles.addAutomobile(Automobile(make,model,color,year,mileage))

def removeAutomobile(automobiles):
    index = int(input("Please enter number of the automobile to be removed >> "))
    automobiles.removeAutomobile(index)

def updateAutomobile(automobiles):
    index = int(input("Please enter number of the automobile to be updated >> "))
    automobile = automobiles.getAutomobile(index)
    make = input("Please enter Make (enter 0 to skip) >> ")
    model = input("Please enter Model (enter 0 to skip) >> ")
    color = input("Please enter Color (enter 0 to skip) >> ")
    year = int(input("Please enter Year (enter 0 to skip) >> "))
    mileage = int(input("Please enter Mileage (enter -1 to skip) >> "))
    if make!='0':
        automobile.setMake(make)
        print("Automobile make is updated")
    if model!='0':
        automobile.setModel(model)
        print("Automobile model is updated")
    if color!='0':
        automobile.setColor(color)
        print("Automobile color is updated")
    if year!=0:
        automobile.setYear(year)
        print("Automobile year is updated")
    if mileage!=-1:
        automobile.setMileage(mileage)
        print("Automobile mileage is updated")

    # create automobile dealership object
automobiles = Automobiledealership()
choice = -1
    # start loop
while choice!=0:
    print()
    print("1. Add sample automobiles to dealership")
    print("2. Display automobiles in the dealership")
    print("3. Add automobile to dealership")
    print("4. Remove automobile from dealership")
    print("5. Update automobile at dealership")
    print("6. Export automobile Inventory")
    print("0. Exit program")

    choice = int(input("Your choice >> "))
    print()

    if choice==1:
        addSampleAutomobiles(automobiles)
    elif choice==2:
        automobiles.printAutomobileList()
    elif choice==3:
        addAutomobile(automobiles)
    elif choice == 4:
        removeAutomobile(automobiles)
    elif choice == 5:
        updateAutomobile(automobiles)
    elif choice == 6:
        f = open('AutomobileList.txt', 'w')
        f.write(str(automobilelist))
        f.close()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: NameError: Automobilelist is not defined

Comment: `automobilelist` doesn't exist.  Would `automobiles.__automobilelist` work?

Comment: I get the error AttributeError: 'Automobiledealership' object has no attribute '__automob
ilelist'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try creating a getter function in your class.

```
def getAutoMobileList(self):
    return self.__automobilelist
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because **automobilelist** is really not defined outside the scope of the **Automobiledealership** class.

If you want to get field from a class, you should call <*InstanceName*>.<*FieldName*>, which in your case is `automobiles.__automobilelist`.

BUT in your case it still won't work. When you prefixed **__automobilelist** with double underscore you defined it as a private member of **Automobiledealership** class, so you should also create a getter function for the **automobilelist** (as you did with **getAutomobile**)

A simple getter function you can use n your class:

```
def getAutoMobileList(self):
    return self.__automobilelist
```

and then call `automobiles.getAutoMobileList()`.

## Another way to solve this:

You called `str(automobilelist)`, which as mentioned above should be `str(automobiles.getAutoMobileList())`, which in turn can be translated to `automobiles.__str__()`. This means that you can define an `__str__` function instead of the getter function mentioned above.
So for a newline separated values you can define:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(str(i) for i in self.__automobilelist)
```

and then just call `str(automobiles)`.

Comment: thank you this was super helpful! Dumb question- are they expected to show in a list or does the text file look jumbled?

Comment: my text file looks like this

Comment: [<__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3d7696990>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3d46f3790>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3ced5ffd0>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3ced5f6d0>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3ced55090>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3ced55110>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3ced55150>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3ced55190>, <__main__.Automobile object at 0x7fe3ced551d0>]

Comment: @SARAH I updated the answer so the `__str__` function would print some useful information